# Parts of BindingList to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, data-binding, c#-3.0, bindinglist

I'm am using the `BindingList` to populate some controls.

On part of a form I need to use some of the data stored within the `BindingList` to create and array.  Say I have `BindingList<CEmployee>` and wanted to retrieve all `CEmployee.Surnames` into a string array how would I go about this without looping through each `CEmployee` in the `BindingList`?

Regards

Taff

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to query the Surnames:

```
var surnames = from employee in myBindingList select employee.Surname;
```

If you need it as an Array, you can use the `ToArray` method of the result:

```
string[] surnamesArray = surnames.ToArray<string>();
```